# rspec save_and_open_page does create an html dump

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, integration-testing

I am trying to use save_and_open_page to see the details of why an rspec test is failing:

**Related Test Code**

```
it { should have_selector('div.alert'); save_and_open_page}
```

the test executes and fails but now output is generated

**Related Gemfile snippet:**

```
group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
  gem 'launchy'
end
```

**Launchy was installed okay:**

```
$ bundle show launchy
//.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/launchy-2.1.2
```

**Related config/test.rb snippet** (I'm expecting the save_and_open_page output to arrive here)

```
Capybara.save_and_open_page_path = 'tmp/test_out'
```

Any ideas why the output does not show up?

Comment: why don't you let capybara use it's default path, which is `Rails.root + "tmp/capybara"`?

Comment: i guess i like to control my own destinations :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try putting the `save_and_open_page` before the failing test:

```
it { save_and_open_page; should have_selector('div.alert') }
```

Otherwise, once it runs `should have_selector('div.alert')`, it won't continue on to the `save_and_open_page` because the test has already failed.